# Whenever I try to create New React Native APP using npx react-native init APP_NAME command it creates typescript instead of javascript project

Tags: react-native

Whenever I try to create New React Native APP using npx react-native init APP_NAME command it creates a typescript instead of a javascript project

I want to create a JS project instead of TSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just replace app.tsx with app.js

Comment: But how do you get the default app.js template vs the app.tsx one?